# What is complexity of this pointer function?

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity

This is code, function receiving a pointer *ptr(that is pointing to character array outside).Loop is simply calculating length. What will be the complexity function of this function. I have calculated.

[image: Complexity Function of this Code]

1. Is this correct complexity function calculation?
2. inside while, should i consider 3 operations, *, **ptr+c** , **!=**
3. Astaric * is dereferencing, ptr+c is calculating address, and != for condition.

Comment: Easy way to find out. For various values of N, benchmark it. Also in *O(N)* type notation you usually simplify *2+4N* to *N*.

Comment: This is not the notation for complexity.

Comment: I need exact complexity function. that i am trying to find.

Comment: Things get really strange once you are told you can't really calculate the complexity of an algorithm.

Comment: Complexity functions are *always*, by definition, approximations. It's just a description saying "does this scale linearly, logarithmically, or is it quadratic" for example. Precise timing does not matter.

Comment: There is no such a thing "exact complexity function".

Comment: Complexity is measured by big O notation.

Comment: OK. we assume complexity functions are approximations. Then, 
question is. should i take them as three operations that are inside while loop?

Comment: By "exact" the OP meant a notation without lower co-efficients removed (so _not_ big-Oh notation) as you well understood.

Comment: @SatishChalasani: That is just _one_ way to measure one kind of complexity; [there are plenty of others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Related_asymptotic_notations).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, Yes, actually, without removing co-efficients, lower order term.

Comment: Not all operations are created equal. Assigning a value and de-referencing a pointer have wildly different performance characteristics. One may take zero cycles, the other a hundred thousand.

Comment: Your terminology is not solid, but your basic thinking is correct.  The function is, indeed, of linear complexity.  "Exact function" is not really possible, since you don't know how long each operation takes.

Comment: Yes, we can say without dropping constants(not big-oh). what will be the complexity function? can i take them three operations inside while loop?

Comment: If you want to count the exact number of instructions executed, you should at least count each kind of instruction separately (because while you can't say e.g. how costly is an addition compared to a modulo, it might however be reasonable to assume that all additions cost more or less the same).  Otherwise, those constants aren't really representative and you might as well omit them. This is rarely done though.

Comment: @JawwadRafiq I would say the best case would be three operation inside the loop if the length is zero. If not, It depends on the length of the array.

Comment: I just wanted to count them for education purpose. then after calculation of total count. I will remove the lower terms. And i will get the worst case(big(o)) that is O(N) in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends strongly on the definition of "complexity" that you're using (certainly this is not one of [the typical asymptotic notations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Related_asymptotic_notations)) but, if I properly remember these assignments from this level of education, yes you have counted correctly.

The resulting worst-case asymptotic algorithmic complexity in big-Oh notation would be `O(N)` (derived by eliding the co-efficients and lower terms (sort of)).

Answer (score 4):

When we say O(N), we *really* mean O(N)+c, where c is a constant.  This is because with *very small n*, the characteristics of the complexity may not show themselves, as nonessentials (noise) may dominate more, so this is represented by *c*.  But as N grows, the constant becomes insignificant, as the complexity as relative to N becomes the dominant time.  Typically, a constant merely shifts the graph up or down by a small amount, but doesn't change its shape.  Thus, we omit it, and just say O(N), which is what we're really interested in knowing.

As for coefficients, same thing happens.  If a complexity is proportional to N, it is a linear relationship.  The graph of a linear operation, multiplied by X, will have a different *slope* but its shape is still linear.  Thus, the coefficient is not really providing additional information in terms of complexity category.

Similarly, if you have something that is O(N)+O(N^2), the N^2 dominates, and we tend to ignore the smaller terms O(N), and just call it O(N^2) algorithm.  It's not an exact science, it's a categorization to understand the nature of the complexity.  Big-oh notation is the *worst case* complexity.

I think you might be interested in the coefficients and constants only when evaluating the relative metrics of specific algorithms that have the same categorical complexity.  (Some O(N*lg(n)) sorts are faster than others, for example.)  But usually it is measured a different way.

Comment: When we say `O(N)` we actually mean there exist `a` and `b` such that the function is always less than or equal to `aN+b`.